# How to listen named pipe and socket at the same time in python

Tags: python, linux, sockets, select, named-pipes

I need to listen to socket with xmpp connection for incoming messages and named pipe (debian linux) at the same time.

The main trouble, as i see it, is that everything freezes after

```
os.open('/var/mypipes/outgoing', os.O_RDONLY)
```

waiting for pipe, so, variants like

```
list = {socket.here:'xmpp',os.open('/var/mypipes/outgoing', os.O_RDONLY):'mypipe'}
while online:
   (i, o, e) = select.select(list.keys(),[],[],1)
   for key in i:
       do smth
```

won't work, and even if I'll put that thing into select.select:

```
while online:
   (i, o, e) = select.select([socket.here,os.open('/var/mypipes/outgoing', os.O_RDONLY)],[],[],1)
   for key in i:
       do smth
```

it doesn't work also.
I'm not a great pro in python, as you can see, so if you could only tell me, where to dig for a solution, that will be more than enough. Buuut... ready-made solution is also nice. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, O_NONBLOCK solves the issue of blocking, and the select works afterwars, the following code runs on my system:

```
import os
import select
l = {os.open('/tmp/pipe', os.O_RDONLY|os.O_NONBLOCK):'mypipe'}

while True:
    (i, o, e) = select.select(l.keys(),[],[],1)
    for key in i:
        print os.read(key, 1)
```

All you'll have to do is to ignore the errors when the pipe is closed...